# I am trying to find a way to show user attribute in some other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is what i did

```
def new
  @refill = Refill.new
  @refill_number = User.find(:id).phone_number
end
```

but obviously didnt work. so what do i need to do? to find user's phonenumber and put it in refils controller. thanks in advance

Comment: How is the user phone number related to a refill?

Comment: Its user has many refills and phone number is user attribute

Comment: most rails applications create a `current_user` method in the ApplicationController which is then available in all of your controllers - typically the method pulls the user_id from the session and then calls `User.find` with that value - there are many authentication gems available to use - https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication - and most of them add the current_user for you

Comment: `User.find(:id).phone_number` needs to pass an integer not a symbol, i.e. `User.find(1).phone_number` or `User.find(session[:user_id]).phone_number` or possibly `User.find(params[:user_id]).phone_number`

Comment: None of them worked unfortunately. i am noob. learning and building at the same time. here is my problem, i have user model with phone number, and refill model with refill amount, when user tries to create the refill his/her phone number is shown next to the phone number because that is the number where its being refilled. users phone number is in user model.

Comment: What did not work for you?, can you explain your problem by adding some more information.

Comment: i want to show this in refill/new "<%= "You are refilling in #{@refill_number}" %>" so i wanted to pull phone number from user model and put it in refill controller.

Comment: try to print the user object in your view.
In controller : @user= User.find(:id) and in your view <%= @user.inspect%>

Comment: so there is no user, that is why you did not get any value, but before that you would have got error when you try to find phone number a for a nil class in the controller itself, check with your log file.
Make sure you have the user in the table.

Comment: I have user in the table. i am logged in but its saying nil lol. idk why

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help?

```
@refill_number = User.find(params[:id]).select(:phone_number)
```

You should really show us how that action is being rendered (for example, how are you passing the `:id` variable to it?)

Comment: i am new to rails.this is what i have done and trying to do, i have refills model and refills controller, user model and user controller, user model has phone number which i want to show in refills/new, just display.

Comment: What i want to learn and am confused with is, how to show various models info and stuff in views of other controllers? How do they relate each other? how to make them relate each other? Where do i put the methods for the parmas and how they are passed? for example, i have wallet model and wallet controller, when user refills through refill controller i want the amount deducted from wallet? how can i achieve that?

Comment: i want to port a site that i use at work to rails, and learn in process. i am pretty familiar with ruby, and in railssome things just confuse me. rite now i am stuck at how to make models comunicate with each other. like i have refill model, wallet model, and user model, refill belongs to wallet, wallet belongs to user and has many refills, user has one wallet and has many refills through wallet. i have all tables set, but how do i make them work together, like when user refills, :balance from wallet will be deducted, and the refills witll go to user's :phone_number. what is the term called?

Comment: how do i search it online? can you point me to links which talks about exactly that?